# Celery Internal error with 'i' format

Tags: python, celery

I get the error below when I try to execute a task with celery and amqp, is there a problem with my configuration. How do I fix this?

```
[2012-06-12 16:49:37,231: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Task core.tasks.sanity[c44c8058-46d1-48cd-a687-0481f5bd5ee5] INTERNAL ERROR: error("'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nobackup/vivenara/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/execute/trace.py", line 192, in trace_task
    R = I.handle_error_state(task, eager=eager)
  File "/nobackup/vivenara/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/execute/trace.py", line 91, in handle_error_state
    }[self.state](task, store_errors=store_errors)
  File "/nobackup/vivenara/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/execute/trace.py", line 114, in handle_failure
    task.backend.mark_as_failure(req.id, exc, self.strtb)
  File "/nobackup/vivenara/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 96, in mark_as_failure
    traceback=traceback)
  File "/nobackup/vivenara/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 229, in store_result
    return self._store_result(task_id, result, status, traceback, **kwargs)
  File "/nobackup/vivenara/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py", line 121, in _store_result
    "traceback": traceback})
  File "/nobackup/vivenara/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 272, in _ensured
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/nobackup/vivenara/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py", line 97, in _publish_result
    self._create_producer(task_id, connection).publish(meta)
  File "/nobackup/vivenara/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py", line 87, in _create_producer
    self._create_binding(task_id)(connection.default_channel).declare()
  File "/nobackup/vivenara/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 386, in declare
    self.queue_declare(nowait, passive=False)
  File "/nobackup/vivenara/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 408, in queue_declare
    nowait=nowait)
  File "/nobackup/vivenara/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/channel.py", line 1376, in queue_declare
    args.write_table(arguments)
  File "/nobackup/vivenara/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/serialization.py", line 378, in write_table
    table_data.write(pack('>i', v))
error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

Comment: What version of RabbitMQ are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.8.2 on a RHEL box

Comment: Have you set a custom CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES?  In the stacktrace it's trying to serialize a queue declare command to the amqp binary framing format, it would make sense to get this error if the result expiry value was of some other type than float/int or out of range.

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact I did set a custom value but it is much less than 2147483647 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value overflow when storing a result:

```
error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

A bigint/long value is being written into the AMQP queue, while it recognizes it as int. 
It is not a configuration issue I believe. What is the value you try to save as a result?

I see in the stack trace:

```
return self._store_result(task_id, result, status, traceback, **kwargs)
```

Can you check what is the result value? Probably this is some strange value...

**EDIT**:

```
task.backend.mark_as_failure(req.id, exc, self.strtb)
```

So in this case it returns exc as result:

```
def mark_as_failure(self, task_id, exc, traceback=None):
        """Mark task as executed with failure. Stores the execption."""
        return self.store_result(task_id, exc, status=states.FAILURE,
                                 traceback=traceback)
```

Could it be the thrown exception from the task to contain a bigint status code?

Comment: That's what I thought initially but the result is a simple Boolean True/False value.

Comment: task.backend.mark_as_failure(req.id, exc, self.strtb) - it seems the task has failed. So it probably uses a different return value/code.

Comment: It seems it returns the exception(exc) as result here... Can you check what kind of exception does the code fire? It could be some exception with code=big_int, and then if it tries to serialize it and push to AMQP ... Try wrapping with try:except your code and re-throw a custom exception with some debugging details.

Comment: Well, after trying things for a while, I decided to change the result backend from amqp to redis and I got the exception that was raised.